# Span with background image and no content

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a span that has no content, but i need a background image (an arrow, by the way).

The problem is without no content inside span the background doesnt appear.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Why not use a block level elment instead? Span is an in-line element and requires the display attribute set to block to do what a div element would do by default.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Set the width; and height properties of the span.

```
<span style="width: 90px; height: 90px; background-image: url('bg.jpg'); display:block" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `style="padding-left:20px"`.

or set `display:block; width:20px; height:20px`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use **display:block**. You can use **position: absolute**. Set width and height as 100%. It will take the image width and height. So resize the image as per your need. And also image will be vertically center aligned to the text. Below is an example. In this I have used 20X20 px image.

```
<html>
<style>
.spanImage{
    background-image: url('settings.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>This is a sample demo.<span class="spanImage"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a nonbreaking space inside, i.e.:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: This is the simplest one out there for showing span without any content inside.

Answer (score 1):

output:

[image: Span with background image and no content]

```css
.foot-link-icon-das {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('https://da.systems/images/ic-registrar-das.svg');
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="foot-link-icon-das"></span>SomeText
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set it to block it will automatically place under other element and this can cause some problems in yyour design.
To prevent this you can use advantages of inline and block together by setting `display:inline-block`this will place like inline and you will be allowed to give height and width to it.
Ps: This doesnt work on ie7.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
<span style="display:block;width:arrow_width;height:arrow_height;background-image:url('image_name');">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: The font-size makes no difference.  ` Width `, ` height `, and ` display: block ` need to be set.  That is all that matters.